# Jump to Declaration when file is in another folder/directory

Tags: python, pycharm

I use a keyboard shortcut for "Jump to declaration" in PyCharm constantly.  I'd like my project structure to conveniently support having source code files in multiple folders/directories.  Unfortunately, it seems that "jump to declaration" fails when attempting to jump to a function call that exists in another directory.  Is there any way to fix this or teach it where to jump?  It seems it's not indexing/searching into nested directories despite those directories being in the same project.  So i'm forced to keep all of my source code in the same directory so I can have a working "jump to declaration" in PyCharm...

I'm importing files from other folders via this solution: 
[Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

```
# some_file.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')

import file
```

But then when I try to "jump to declaration" via keyboard shortcut of file.function(), it fails because it's not in the same directory of the current file i'm in.

**Edit:**

So I created the structure @Code-Apprentice suggested.

[image]

Then I added the __init__.py that @Lukasz suggested and it worked:

[image]

Now back to my other project, the __init__.py didn't seem to work.  Let me tinker and see what the differences are.

**Edit2:**

Interesting, so if add the same exact file, bar.py to a subfolder of my original project with the __init__.py file included, I cannot jump to declaration there.  So there must be something wrong with this project or PyCharm's interpretation of my project.  It's a big project, maybe something is throwing it off.

**Edit3:**

The last issue was a dumb mistake on my part. Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you give a complete code example? I frequently use Ctrl+B to jump to declarations in python source files no matter what directory the declaration is in relative to the current source.

Comment: You are welcome!;]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could You add some code and file structure?
You need empty `__init__.py` files in folders to make them python package, so imports will work for modules
You can import also:

```
from app.folder1 import name [as sub_name]
```

Comment: This worked for my example, let me see if I can successfully apply this to my other project.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your project directory `PROJECT_ROOT`. You can create any arbitrary directory structure in this folder. So for example, say you create `bar.py` in a `foo` folder and `main.py` in `PROJECT_ROOT`:

```
PROJECT_ROOT
|_ foo
   |_ bar.py
|_ main.py
```

In `main.py` use standard imports:

```
import foo.bar

foo.bar.do_something()
```

Now move the cursor to the usage of `do_something()` in `main.py` and press Ctrl+B. This will jump to the definition in `foo/bar.py`.

Comment: Set up this project, see edits above. Got it working in example project now.